# Why do we only see female Children of the Forest and male White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why are all of the Children of the Forest female and all of the White Walkers are male?

Is there a relation between them?

Comment: Not really sure how we can answer this at this point... we don't have any information from the show...

Comment: (Spoiler /!\) Note that there is a [Night's queen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Night's_Queen) mentioned in the book

Comment: There is nothing in the show or books that say the Children are all female or anything. They are childlike and ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, don't think that the premise of this question is correct. There are at least legends of female white walkers in the books, and the CotF aren't all female. We've just seen a very small group of CotF and Others.

Comment: I was wondering why (in the tv show) the CotF are all female (and the WW male). I don't think that's a rule. Maybe in the books or in the world of GoT there's a explanation. Maybe is a coincidence (or not)

Comment: I think it's actually just a psychological technique employed by the script writers to help you feel that the Others (CotF), despite their unusual and freakish appearance, are kind souls and are on the 'good side'.  
In most cultures, women are seen as gentle and caring, while inversely, men are seen as strong and unattached.  This carries across to the White Walkers who are 'aged', expressionless and ragged. Combine that with their obvious violence and your mind has no doubt that they are evil.

Comment: Re-watch Hardhome - I think women and men both were turned by the walkers in the attack. The group shots you're seeing might be recycled composites with basically the same bunch of actors.

Comment: @ionstar Wrights, they were turn into Zombies, I mean Wrights, Not Walkers.

Comment: @ReeceDodds If this was the case they all would be women, at least according to your argumentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding White Walkers specifically, my understanding is that they are somehow created by sacrifice of human beings. (This is borne out on the show in the depiction of the creation of the first White Walker.) On the male question, you can look to Craster. Craster sacrifices only male children to the White Walkers. [Note that there is a distinction between ["Wights"](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wight) and the White Walker masters who re-animate them.]

Regarding the Children of the Forest, it does seem as though the TV version only shows females, but @cde 's answer that they are "childlike" and thus "ambiguous" is almost certainly correct.